# How to calculate "total" column for has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have 3 models

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_items
  has_many :items, through: :order_items
end

class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :item
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_items
  has_many :orders, through: :order_items
end
```

For this model, such migration was created

```
class CreateOrder < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :priority
      t.text :description
      t.integer :order_item_id
      t.decimal :total

      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :items do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :type
      t.integer :order_item
      t.text :description
      t.decimal :cost

      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :order_items do |t|
      t.belongs_to :order, index: true
      t.belongs_to :item, index: true
      t.integer :count

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I do not understand how can I calculate `total` for orders? That is `total = count * cost`. And how to use here counter cache?

Comment: The main thing is that the `total` column of order is automatically filled. and filled it by multiplying `count`(order_item) to `price`(item)

Comment: Your tables are a bit of a mess right now it appears that an `Order` belongs to an `OrderItem` due to the `order_item_id` and `Item` has a strange integer column named `order_item` which I don't understand at all. but the total would just be `self.total = order_items.joins(:items).sum('order_items.count * items.cost')` you can add hooks to the `OrderItem` class to handle creates, updates and deletions.

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested)
LINE 1: SELECT SUM(order_items.count * items.cost) FROM "order_items...
                   ^
: SELECT SUM(order_items.count * items.cost) FROM "order_items" INNER JOIN "items" ON "items"."id" = "order_items"."item_id" WHERE "order_items"."order_id" = $1

Comment: Not sure I understand how that results in a nested aggregate function is that the full query?

Comment: I paste you code into my model, after i get this error. May be you know what happened?